# Getting android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package in custom notification

Tags: android, remoteview

I am trying to create a custom notification using the remote view.

Steps Followed:
1. Created a layout and placed in the res/layout folder
2. Extended the RemoteViews class and implemented some helper methods.
3. Instantiated an object of the Extended class and I am supplying this as Content by using setContent() in the Notification.Builder.
4. Cached the instantiated Extended class.

Now most of the times when I do an operation even before supplying the extended class object to the Notification.Builder its crashing.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10194): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from
package com.motorolasolutions.ptt.mpttclient: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: 
StatusBarNotification
```

I have tried following functions

```
setBoolean(R.id.textview1, "setEnabled", false);
```

Please let me know how can I call the functions on the remote view.

I tried so many functions which have @android.view.RemotableViewMethod tag in the source code of Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventhough "setEnabled" function has the @RemotableViewMethod  tag in the base class (View.java). This is being overridden in the derived class and doesn't have the @RemotableViewMethod tag. We have to check the tag of the child class if its being overridden.